Blackbody Radiation Simulation Software
I am trying to model the effective radiating temperatures of various three-dimensional solids (Tetrahedron, cube, octahedron, etc.) given a specific incident radiation. Are there any (free) softwares available for something like that?

I’m voting to close this question because questions asking for software recommendations are generally off-topic.
